# How to fuzzy match a ruby on rails elasticsearch.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have a controller action that allows me to search for `Document` via the document GUID. The issue is that the GUIDs are 20+ characters. I would like to be able to search for the document using just say the first 5 characters of the GUID.

What I currently have is:

```
search_params = { sort: { sent_at: :desc } }

if can_search && params[:document_id].present?
    search_params[:filter] = { term: { "_id" => params[:document_id] } }
    @documents = Elasticsearch::Model.search(search_params, [Document])
else
    @documents = Elasticsearch::Model.search(search_params, [Document]).page(params[:page]).per(20)
end
```

This works fine if I enter the exact GUID. But partial matching doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can using [WildcardQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html#query-dsl-wildcard-query) like that

```
search_params[:filter] = { wildcard: { "_id" => "*#{params[:document_id]}*" } }
```